# How to separate long uBlock Origin (uBO) static filters (rules) across multiple lines?

Tags: browser-addons, web-filtering, traffic-filtering, ublock-origin, internet-filter

I seem to recall that there is a way to separate (continue) long uBlock Origin (uBO) static filters across multiple lines to improve filter readability.

I looked through the Wiki and could not find a correct description of how to accomplish this task.

I'm interested in learning the correct syntax for doing this for static network filters and static cosmetic filters.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax

"Starting with 1.26.0 (commit one, two), very long filters can split into multiple lines: append space and backslash character to the first line and indent continuation line by four spaces."

Comment: Thanks Joep.  Can you get that to work?  I've tried it at least a dozen times, and it doesn't work for me.  uBO always reports the first line as an error.